# Copiar celulas para outro worksheet se não existir

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Na worksheet "BASE" introduzo vários dados do cliente (NIF, nome, morada, telefone, email). Tenho uma worksheet "DADOS" onde tem uma lista de vários clientes.

Eu necessito de criar um botão na worksheet "BASE" que copia os dados do cliente para a worksheet "DADOS" se não existir baseando-se no NIF mas caso exista atualiza a informação na worksheet "DADOS".

Também necessito de criar um botão na worksheet "BASE" que procura na WS "DADOS" um determinado "NIF" e copia a informação para a WS "BASE".

Espero que me consigam ajudar. Não tenho muita experiência com vba e isto vai-me poupar muito trabalho.

Obrigado

Answer (score -1):

Vamos lá.
Se eu entendi direito, esse NIF seria o índice da planilha? Nesse caso o seguinte código deve te ajudar:

```
Sub copiar()

lRow1 = Plan1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lRow2 = Plan2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lCol1 = Plan1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lCol2 = Plan2.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 2 To lRow1
    x = 0
    For d = 2 To lRow2

        If Plan1.Cells(i, 1).Value = Plan2.Cells(d, 1).Value Then

            For b = 1 To lCol1

                Plan2.Cells(d, b).Value = Plan1.Cells(i, b).Value

            Next b
            x = x + 1
            Exit For

        End If

    Next d

    If x = 0 Then
        lRow2 = lRow2 + 1
        For b = 1 To lCol1

            Plan2.Cells(lRow2, b).Value = Plan1.Cells(i, b).Value

        Next b
    End If


Next i


End Sub
```

Esse código ira verificar se o que esta na linha `i` da `Plan1` (BASE) existe na `Plan2` (DADOS) verificando se o NIF já existe, caso não exista ele copia e repete o processo para a próxima linha até acabar as linhas preenchidas no `Plan1`(DADOS).

Comment: Na Plan1 (BASE) só tenho uma linha com informações. Na Plan2 (DADOS) é que tenho a minha base de dados total à qual eu quero acrescentar mais "clientes" e completar a informação já existente. Logo, se não existe o NIF acrescenta mais uma linha na Plan2 com essa informação. Se existir o NIF substitui essa linha pela nova informação.

Comment: @MCardoso editei a resposta, adicionei a cópia dos dados para quando ele encontrar o NIF na outra tabela. Quanto a você ter apenas uma linha, não é um problema, o código ira rodar enquanto houver linhas preenchidas, então você adicionar apenas uma como disse, ou adicionar N linhas e ele irá rodar enquanto houver linhas para verificar.